# Vibrationsensor keeps giving us the same value and it doesn't change when we "vibrate" it

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

We want to get the value of our vibrationsensor but it keeps giving us the value "677". We are new to programming so we don't really know how to fix this. The problem we encountered is in Arduino IDE

We tried to change the Serial.begin number but that was just a desperate call for help which obviously didn't work. We also tried to put the the power input in another port. First we put it in the 5V port, but it only gave us the value 1023, which is the max (I think). But then we put it in the 3.5V port and it gave us 677, which is a bit better but it doesn't change no matter how much we vibrate it.

Our code is:

```
int vibrationsensor = A0;
int vibrationvalue;

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(vibrationsensor, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    vibrationvalue = analogRead(vibrationsensor);
    Serial.println(vibrationvalue);
    delay(300);
}
```

We expected that the output would be consistent when the area is not vibrating and that it would change when we would vibrate it. But at this moment it just gives us 677 which isn't exactly wrong IF the area isn't vibrating, but it stays 677 even when we vibrate it.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, maybe it is a problem with the electrical wiring? What can of sensor is it?

Comment: Our vibrationsensor has serial number: KY-002. It´s the one our school gave us, so we didn´t expect much of it, but it would still need to work. Which it didn´t.

Comment: Without more informations about the wiring and the experiment it is hard to tell where the problem is... The code seems to be correct so the problem might be on the electronic part.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned is a [reference](https://arduinomodules.info/ky-002-vibration-switch-module/) for your sensor:

> it will react to shock and vibration by closing the circuit.

So, this vibration sensor is working in an ON/OFF mode: it will not return a analogic values of the vibration, it will only tell you if there is a shock or not. Seems that this sensor is not adapted to what you want to perform.

Hope it helps,